# Saviing csv file in Mac values are saving with comma and all in one cell

Tags: php, macos, csv, file

I had created a sample for users to download a csv file with a few cells (title, category, price, etc) so they can add their products on this file. The thing is that on windows everything goes well but on Mac this csv file when saved merge all cells in only one separated by comma the values (Product Name, Category name, 0,00, etc).

Someone know how could I deal with this situation? I'm using PHP to get all the values from the csv file.

Comment: Please, show us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from your code.

Comment: I think the concern is with the client opening the csv file. A csv file is by definition a file in which your data is separated by commas. Some tools (spreadsheets) automatically convert data into as many columns and rows. Others don't, in which case it must be converted. In all cases your file is probably identical (win and mac) if you open it with a text editor.